# Reference to UIButton inside a view

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, view, controller

I loaded an `UIView` out of a nib-file. I wrote some methods which I was able to connect to the `First Responder` of the nib. They work fine.

Now I have to reference a `UIButton` which is embedded in the loaded view. But since it's no view controller / just an `UIView` (I guess?), the `File's Owner` does not detect my `IBOutlet UIButton * button` in the `.h`-file.

So what's going on here? Thanks!

Comment: So, connecting the button in your `xib` to the `File Owner` didn't work?

Comment: Have you set the custom class name of the UIView in identity inspector?

Comment: If you've some controls on your uiview, why not to use a uiviewcontroller and use its view? in your way, i think you're going against the MVC pattern..someone correct me if I'm wrong, please, I'm not quite sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a couple of ways to do this.. one of them is..

Set the buttons tag property in interface builder, then in code, loop through all the subviews looking for the view with the tag you set

..Didn't test this, but it should be something like

```
for (UIView *subView in [view subviews]) {
    if (subView.tag == <YOUR TAG HERE>) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)subView;
    }
}
```

..I'd wrap this in a function called getSubviewWithTag so you can reuse it elsewhere

Comment: You really don't need to do this. Use the outlets mechanism of Interface Builder, that's what they are there for.

Comment: ...and if you you are really going to do something like this, then you can get a subview out of your view by tag, using '- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag' ...

Comment: Sometimes I don't know why I bother, if you're not going to listen to the correct way of doing things. This really isn't the correct answer or how to do this properly. There are various other correct answers suggested here, even a diagram!!!

Answer (score 1):

When you drag connections within Interface Builder, you don't always have to connect to Files Owner. Drag from your UIButton, and drop on the UIView that contains it. If it has an IBOutlet UIButton property on you custom UIView class - it will connect up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample of how it can be done:

[image]

Right-click the `UIButton` in the `xib`, click on the referencing dot and drag it to `File's Owner`. As soon as you release the click, a popup appears of all the `IBOutlet`s you can connect the element with.

**EDIT**- If it doesn't turn blue, then you haven't set the Custom Class for your `File's Owner`! You can do that as below. Click on `File's Owner` and then the 3rd tab. Set it to your custom view controller.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know. But `File's Ower` does not turn blue.

Comment: Yes, my class is of kind `UIView`, not `UIViewController`, if I add an ´UIViewController` to my nib-file, the app crashes, and says smt. about not being able to allocate two singleton classes (my VC is a singleton class). Maybe there is a mistake in my code, but where ...?

Comment: Or is there any command to redraw the screen like [tableView refresh ...]? It's just because I animate the view and there are two buttons which stay there (inactive) although the UIView which embedded the buttons is dismissed.

Comment: If it's a `UIView`, then you need to add the target programmatically. Also, why do you need to make your `UIViewController` a singleton? Singletons are for data, not views and controllers!

Comment: I have a music player which should play music and stay controllable all over the app. The connection in one direction (From Button to First Responder) work like a charme, but the other way around it's totally messed up.

Comment: Then instead of making your `UIViewController` a singleton, you should do that for your `AVAudioPlayer`...I think that would be more in sync with the MVC pattern. There's nothing wrong in diverging from MVC! It's just recommended for modularity and to enable quick understanding of code by another developer!

Comment: Yes, AVAudioPlayer is. Solved the problem using tags.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to alloc and subview your button in that specific view.
Then define the action **dynamically** in the .m class of that "View" may that will work for you.

```
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Yes, I know that possibility. But since I want a WYSIWYG option for my customers it's not the best option.